# Htaccess - Remove specific trailing numbers

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My Htaccess file looks like this :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)-(?:[0-9]*)?/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It works perfectly. But for now, it removes all the numbers preceded by an hyphen at the end of my url. And I only need to remove the hyphen, 7 numbers and the ".html" from urls that looks like this :

```
http://www.leblogjeuvideo.be/archive/2014/03/11/annales-de-rolistes-l-appel-de-cthulhu-semaine-17-8130360.html
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)-(?:[0-9]*)?/?$ [NC]
```

with this one :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)-(?:\d\d\d\d\d\d\d*)?/?$ [NC]
```

and it seems to work.

If somebody can confirm that I'm doing it correctly.

Thanks a lot.